# how to detect if image from photo library was taken by iPhone camera or imported

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, camera-roll

in the app i am developing, i ought to know if the picture selected by the user was originally taken by the iPhone's camera, or is it a picture taken from any other source, as from the internet or imported from external camera etc.

Comment: Try the EXIF-data of the photo.

Comment: try to read meta data of the image.

Comment: thanks @yoeriboven, it seems to work as imported photos don't have the location value, when examining the ALAssetsLibrary -> valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation. is it sufficient to see if the location is null to determine?

Comment: @wwwwwwn Never worked with it before, so can't help you with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @yoeriboven pointed out, you should check the image EXIF. The easiest way to access it would be:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *metaData = [assetRep metadata];
```

This should be the relevant section:

```
"{TIFF}" = {
    DateTime = "2012:12:13 01:21:55";
    Make = Apple;
    Model = "iPhone 4";
    Orientation = 6;
    ResolutionUnit = 2;
    Software = "6.0.1";
    XResolution = 72;
    YResolution = 72;
    "_YCbCrPositioning" = 1;
};
```

I wouldn't count only on the location property. Non iPhone photos can have location as well.